# Addition of Unbounded Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-theory, inner-products

Let $H$ be a (separable complex) Hilbert space and let $A$ and $B$ be two densely-defined, maximally-defined linear operators on $H$ with domains $D(A)$ and $D(B)$ respectively.  (By maximall-defined, I mean that $A$ and $B$ admit no extensions).  Then, we can define the operator $A+B$ on $D(A)\cap D(B)$, however, in general, the operator $\left( D(A)\cap D(B),A+B\right)$ will not be maximally-defined.  The question is:  does this operator admit a *unique* maximal extension?

My conjecture is that the answer is no, but I would absolutely love for the answer to be yes.

Any ideas?

Thanks again!

Comment: Well, $D(A) \cap D(B)$ can be almost empty, no? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Well, that has been the route I've been taking to try to find a counterexample, that is, try to make $D(A)\cap D(B)$ as small as possible, but no luck yet.  What exactly did you have in mind?

Comment: In case you're wondering why I'm interested, I am trying to turn the collection of all densely-defined linear operators on $H$ into a $^*$-algebra, where two operators are considered equal iff they have the same domain and agree on that domain.  I then added the condition of being maximally-defined so that we have equality with $A^{**}=A$.  But then, I just realized, it is not obvious (and probably not true) that addition is well-defined, hence the question.

Comment: I will think about an example in the morning if nobody else has given one, I'm too tired now.

Comment: If you add the requirement of self-adjointness (so a symmetric operator must have the same domain as its adjoint to be "self-adjoint"), you can avoid the particular issue of having no maximally-defined operators, as in Robert I's answer below. In general, there is not a _unique_ self-adjoint extension of a symmetric operator, of course, and compositions of self-adjoint are not necessarily self-adjoint in any case... but this notion may clarify some technicalities for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no maximally-defined operators except those defined everywhere.  That is, if $D(A)$ is any proper subspace of $H$, you can take any $u \notin D(A)$ and define an extension $\tilde{A}$ on $D(\tilde{A}) = \text{span}(D(A),u)$ by $\tilde{A}(x+cu) = Ax$ for $x \in D(A)$ and scalars $c$.

Perhaps you might be interested in operators related to self-adjoint operators.  There I have a little result that you might find interesting.  Let $A$ be any self-adjoint unbounded linear operator with purely discrete spectrum.  Consider $T = U A$ and $T^* = A U^*$ where $U$ is a unitary operator.  Then the set of $U$ for which ${\cal D}(T) \cap {\cal D}(T^*) = \{0\}$ is a dense $G_\delta$ in the unitary operators on $H$.

Comment: @Robert: do you have a reference to your result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually I should have said, contains a dense $G_\delta$.  See "Some Generic Results in Mathematical Physics", Markov Processes and Related Fields 10 (2004), 517-521.